# Como simplificando ações de scroll to section e back to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho as funções de rolagem suave do menu para sessões de uma One Page, bem como um Back to Top suave:

```
var $doc = $('html, body');

$('a').not('#back-to-top').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $doc.animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
});

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#back-to-top').addClass('show');
    } else {
        $('#back-to-top').removeClass('show');
    }
});

$('#back-to-top').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $doc.animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 700);
});
```

css:

```
#back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: 35px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
#back-to-top:hover {
    background: #000;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
#back-to-top.show {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Como simplificar essas ações, seria possível unificar em uma única ação?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema produzindo o seguinte resultado:

Botão voltar ao topo (**btn-scroll-top**):

```
<a href="#" id="btn-scroll-top" class="back-to-top" title="Voltar ao topo">&uarr;</a>
```

Já para rolar até a ancora basta criar um link com a classe **scrollPage** e uma ancora. Exemplo:

```
<!-- link -->
<a class="scrollPage" href="#contato">Contato</a>

<!-- ancora -->
<a id="contato"></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.scrollPage, .back-to-top').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($.attr(this, 'href') != '#') ? $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top : 0
    }, 500);
});

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100)
        $('#btn-scroll-top').addClass('show');
    else
        $('#btn-scroll-top').removeClass('show');
});
```

css:

```
#btn-scroll-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: 35px;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

#btn-scroll-top:hover {
    background: #000;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

#btn-scroll-top.show {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```